# Density of two algebraic curves with maximum number of intersection points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f$ and $g$ be two complex polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$ with two variables respectively and coefficients of these two polynomials correspond to $M=\mathbb{C}^\frac{(n+1)(n+2)+(m+1)(m+2)}{2}$ with Euclidean topology. It is well-known by Bezout's theorem that these two polynomials have at most $nm$ intersection points in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Let $N$ be the set composed of coefficients of $f$ and $g$ which have $nm$ intersection points in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Is $N$ an open dense subset in $M$? And what is the answer if we change field $\mathbb{C}$ ($\mathbb{CP}^2$) into $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{RP}^2$) ?

It is obvious that $N$ is open by implicit function theorem, but how to prove the dense part. Sorry I do not major in complex algebraic geometry, maybe this question is too easy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Openness follows from the theorem of Bertini.

Comment: Just to add to what Sasha said, once openness is proved in the Zariski topology, non-emptiness just requires a single example. I am fairly certain one can come up with one fairly easily, for every pair of possible degrees.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao: $(x-z)(x-2z)\dots(x-mz)=0$ and $(y-z)(y-2z)\dots(y-nz)=0$ will do.

Comment: @Sasha Can it be more detailed please? I think this result need Bertini's theorem too, but I do not know how to make sure one variety is smooth in the proof. Sorry for my lackness of knowledges in algebraic geometry.